# Why was my post deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-posts

I'm new here (the 100 rep is due to my other account(s) on SE), though I'm not new to SE.

Why was [my answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/389649/236530) (an answer to [Why is the misspelling of "its" (possessive) so widespread?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389614/why-is-the-misspelling-of-its-possessive-so-widespread)) deleted? The main point of my answer is that `its` really should have been `it's`, something that the asker seems unaware of. As for the numbered questions - should a detailed explained answer be given to each one of them? They seem secondary to the main question. Or is (attempted) humor frowned upon here?

[image]

Also, I think that in StackOverflow, *deleting* an answer (as opposed to downvoting) is usually reserved for spam/offensive language /etc. Is it different here?

(And by the way, the question there was marked as a duplicate of quite a different question. It does not look like a duplicate at all.)

Comment: The "my answer" link just links to the page. Users below a certain rep cannot see deleted answers. You can screenshot it and post the image, though.

Comment: @Hank Done. Thanks. (It had 2 upvotes at first. I assume it also got a downvote.)

Comment: RegDwight is probably the best person to answer this but that answer is very poorly written when it comes to not just its structure and organization, but also it's content. No offense.

Comment: To explain my fairly harsh comment above, I mainly mean the numbered section. That's not a very readable and informative section. Simple yes and no doesn't bode well here; you have to explain your answers more.

Comment: I might as well make my plea here. Please Josh undelete your answer. If my two comments annoyed you, and compelled you to delete your answer, I apologise.

Comment: @ispiro In a nutshell,  agree that the duplicate question is quite different from delavnog's. I cast my vote to close his Q because it is POB: primarily opinion-based. As to why your answer was deleted, I'm afraid only RegDwight can answer that, but my guess is  that it seems to be only expressing your opinion, an idea, it lacks solid evidence whereas Josh's answer is made of several reputable references, but lacks that personal analysis and summary.

Comment: @Hank The numbered questions are mainly opinion/guess-based. I originally didn't even answer them. But perhaps you're right that that was the reason.

Comment: @ispiro We can only speculate at this point.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Unless someone actually did research, asking people why they made this mistake, which I doubt anyone has, the answer to this question is bound to be opinion based.

Comment: I couldn't make any sense of what you wrote. It could easily have been flagged as 'low quality' and then reviewers could recommend to delete or mods delete if they agree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume it's because your answer starts with "I assume it's because", and that shows that it's only your assumption, and we don't welcome assumptions in the answer box on the main ELU site. Try the comments box instead, and that we don't usually mind.

As far as I know, what you wrote after "as far as I know" is unclear, to me, at least. Try quoting relevant portion of the question inside your answer or, better yet, write sentences, not simply yeses and nos.

One of my canned comments for poor answers is this:

> Please [explain your answer](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), preferably with some supporting statements and [references](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). While opinions are valued, they are not of much help as answers.

I [welcome you to ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour), and I'm sure you’ll get the hang of it after a while.

Comment: a) Thanks. b) Your comment would have been more welcome than my answer being deleted. Now I can't even improve my answer. As for the "as far as I know" part - I didn't really answer that part at first. It doesn't seem like it needs answers besides the main answer.

Comment: @ispiro Consider revising your deleted answer and then raising a flag requesting undeletion. It's all undoable.

Comment: @MetaEd Thanks. Question revised, and flag raised.

Comment: Thanks! My revised answer got undeleted. (And thanks for the formatting.) And thank you,  @MetaEd◆, for that.